# Message tray does not give live updates forThunderbird, Gwibber, Emphathy. Is this supposed to be like this?

Tags: 12.10, thunderbird, gwibber, messaging-tray

I am running a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.10. I entered my account details in the online accounts app. In the message tray icon in the systray, thunderbird, Gwibber, Empathy all just have links to the app. Unless the thunderbird,gwibber,emphathy itself in running, the message tray doesnt give live updates if i receive a email or message. Is this supposed to be like this?

Comment: Yes, you have to have the program running for the message indicator to get info about the program, else how is it going to get info from software that isn't running?.

Comment: So this could be solved by adding them as start up applications, if you then close them they are still running in the background]

Answer (score 0):

I am using 12.04.1 with cinnamon and not using empathy, but you can give a try

Thunderbird :

1. Get "systray" addon
2. Check mark on "Start application hidden to tray"
3. Add thundebird to startup on login by add it to start application

Pidgin

1. Get "Extended preference" plug-in
2. Set plugin, click/check mark "Hide buddy list at startup"
3. Add Pidgin to startup

Gwibber more easier just go to preference > check mark on "Start service at login"